# interactive content beneath a transparent image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently on this project:
http://www.webjor.com.br/

as you can see, the background for the header is pretty big, it have 900px height and comes all the way down the page, is stays over the content in the middle... aaaand thats my problem, I need the content to be clickable, so I can use buttons and outer stuff.. do you guys have any idea how I can do that? I don't wanna to slice the header background, it will be pretty anoying to fits the pattern if i did that..

Comment: Not sure what you want is doable...

Comment: @Pointy actually a simple css solution

Comment: @charlietfl What really scares me about this css rule is that I wouldn't be surprised to see it deprecated one day because they really crossed the line between "style sheet" and "controlling event logic using css rules."

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix just thinking similar thoughts...great way to mess a site up injecting a style tag `a {pointer-events: none}`

Comment: Then people will invent the new meaning for XSS, (Cross Site Styling)

Answer (score 4):

Can use CSS `pointer-events: none`...mouse events will pass through the element on top to underlying ones.

Beware however this is a CSS3 feature and not fully supported across all browsers. Personally I would consider redesigning layout

[MDN Pointer-events Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: will work but consider this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events if your userbase might be using a browser that doesn't support it.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix  good point, might need to modify layout for unsupported browsers

Comment: Awesome...learned something new today!!